# Photos won't let me edit anything / Same problem on Sierra

Tags: photos, macos

So (my mom) is trying to edit photos in OS X El Capitan's Photos app and can't seem to do so, all the options are just greyed out. This is true of all the photos in the app.

I looked around online and found a couple of people who had the same issue but no-one ever seemed to have solved it.

[image]

Comment: Where are the pictures stored? You can easily 'paste' a file location into stack exchange by dragging any file to an editable window, like this comments pane, while you're typing. I'm wondering if the source is potentially locked, on an NTFS drive, etc.

Comment: The photos should be in the `Photos Library` folder/collection/whateverosxcallsit, they were imported from iPhotos earlier.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem.  I do notice a (barely visible against light background) exclamation mark in a circle in the lower right corner of the photo, which indicates that my disk is full. (I'm using apple cloud storage.)  So that could be it.